# JavaScript file is not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assert/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assert/js/bootstrap.min.js">
     </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assert/js/jquery-2.1.1.js">
     </script>
```

I link css file same method and it is working, but js file are not working, how to slove this problem please help me....
when i BootstrapCDN link it working correct.

Comment: did you load url helper ?

Comment: Not working means? what issue you are facing?

Comment: how to load url helper?

Comment: when i calling a model of bootstrap it not working and not show thw modal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it will help you. Make sure you have already loaded the URL Helper

```
type="text/javascript"
```

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assert/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>`

OR

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assert/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>`

OR use CDN file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>`

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: i write 'type="text/javascript" ' but it is not working

Comment: yes path is correct when i view page source it show me js file content.

Comment: have you loaded URL helper like this? $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider make sure in source page it should only show javascript content only when you click on the file url

Comment: yes, i load this . Is before load helper what we do in config file?

Comment: in application/config/autoload.php file you can also add URL helper in $autoload['helper'] = array();

Comment: http://localhost/codeigniter/assert/js/jquery-2.1.1.js                                     when i open page source and click on js file it show this type of url.

Comment: is we write url in array(); ?

Comment: yes. you can add if you want to use multiple helpers like this array('helper1', 'helper2', 'helper3')

Comment: JavaScript file content only showing like this? https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js

Comment: i write it but problem is same.

Comment: cdn file is working but my files are not working how to solve problem?

Comment: have you set your base_url() ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

add js in your page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ shabbirhasan this online link is working but my js file are not working in which my own function/methods are called.